# Socket.io: почему постоянно выводятся connected/disconnected

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Такая проблемма:
Пишу чат на `node.js` с применением `Socket.IO`
На сервере установил:

```
io.configure(function() {
io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);})
```

На клиенте ничего не менял, все по дефолту:

```
socket = io.connect();socket.on('connect', function () {socket.emit('setname', name);
$("#chat").append($("<div class=\"system\">"+name+" have joined the party</div> ...
```

Но вот почему у меня разрывается и снова устанавливается соединение, примерно каждые две минуты как этого избежать, где ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

```
io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"])) // Не делайте так, это очень плохо
```

В общем-то, ошибки нет, соединение разрывает потому, что вы используете xhr-polling, идея xhr-polling'а заключается в том, что вы шлете простой xhr запрос серверу, сервер, в свою очередь, удерживает соединение до момента появления информации которую необходимо отправить клиенту,  после отправки данных, естественно, соединение обрывается. Соединение, так-же, может оборваться по таймауту.

PS: Настоятельно рекомендую не отключать поддержку websocket'ов, e.g

```
io.set("transports", ["websocket", "xhr-polling"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

socket.io это прекрасно, но со своей стороны рекомендую посмотреть на весьма неплохую библиотечку - [SockJS - WebSocket emulation](https://github.com/sockjs)

Использую ее для онлайн-браузерной игрульки, реализовал и чат с комнатами, и собственно бой он-лайн.
Достоинства - библиотечка подбирает сама "тип" соединения и достаточно хорошо "держит" связь, а также вполне понятный командный интерфейс.

Comment: >библиотечка подбирает сама "тип" соединения

socket.io, по умолчанию, поступает точно так-же

Comment: верно, но автор библиотеки создал ее потому, что его категорически перестала устраивать степень устойчивости передачи данных сокет.ио... топикстартеру конечно же необходимо разобраться с параметрами сокет.ио, но я ему предлагаю всего лишь альтернативу, если вдруг с сокет.ио не сложится..

Comment: @deivan, "степень устойчивости передачи данных" в socket.io, в первую очередь, зависит от светлой головы на плечах.